# Deploying Rails 3.1 app to heroku error (sqlite3->Postgresql)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, deployment, sqlite, heroku

I am having trouble with deploying rails 3.1. app to heroku.

After some research, I found out that the main reason behind the issue  is this - http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/how-do-i-use-sqlite3-for-development

After changing my gem file:

```
group :production do
 gem 'pg'
end
group :development, :test do
 gem 'sqlite3'
end
```

Still the "We're sorry, but something went wrong." page error.

Here is the log file:

```
 ←[36m2011-11-26T16:34:31+00:00 heroku[api]:←[0m Add-on add logging:basic by emil
 s.veveris@thrillengine.com
 ←[36m2011-11-26T16:34:31+00:00 heroku[api]:←[0m Release v2 created by emils.veve
 ris@thrillengine.com
 ←[36m2011-11-26T16:34:31+00:00 heroku[api]:←[0m Add-on update shared-database
 ←[36m2011-11-26T16:34:31+00:00 heroku[api]:←[0m Release v3 created by emils.veve
 ris@thrillengine.com
 ←[33m2011-11-26T16:43:15+00:00 heroku[slugc]:←[0m Slug compilation started
 ←[36m2011-11-26T16:44:17+00:00 heroku[api]:←[0m Deploy 277a3f4 by emils.veveris@
 thrillengine.com
 ←[36m2011-11-26T16:44:17+00:00 heroku[api]:←[0m Release v4 created by emils.veve
  ris@thrillengine.com
 ←[32m2011-11-26T16:44:18+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m State changed from created to
  starting
 ←[33m2011-11-26T16:44:18+00:00 heroku[slugc]:←[0m Slug compilation finished
 ←[32m2011-11-26T16:44:28+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m State changed from starting to
  up
 ←[35m2011-11-26T17:09:51+00:00 heroku[nginx]:←[0m 81.198.241.178 - - [26/Nov/201
  1:09:09:51 -0800] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 728 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:
  8.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/8.0" stormy-night-6239.heroku.com
 ←[32m2011-11-26T18:12:59+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m Idling
 ←[32m2011-11-26T18:13:00+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m State changed from up to down
 ←[32m2011-11-26T18:13:00+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m State changed from down to cre
  ated
 ←[32m2011-11-26T18:13:01+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m State changed from created to
 starting
 ←[32m2011-11-26T18:13:02+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m Stopping process with SIGTERM
 ←[32m2011-11-26T18:13:02+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m >> Stopping ...
 ←[32m2011-11-26T18:13:02+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m Process exited
 ←[32m2011-11-26T18:13:11+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m >> Thin web server (v1.2.6 codena
  me Crazy Delicious)
 ←[32m2011-11-26T18:13:11+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m >> Maximum connections set to 102
  4
 ←[32m2011-11-26T18:13:11+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m >> Listening on 0.0.0.0:29604, CT
 RL+C to stop
 ←[32m2011-11-26T18:13:12+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m State changed from starting to
 up
 ←[32m2011-11-26T19:16:24+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m Idling
 ←[32m2011-11-26T19:16:25+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m State changed from up to down
 ←[32m2011-11-27T11:29:48+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m Unidling
 ←[32m2011-11-27T11:29:48+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m State changed from down to cre
 ated
 ←[32m2011-11-27T11:29:50+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m State changed from created to
 starting
 ←[32m2011-11-27T11:29:53+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m Starting process with command
 `thin -p 16668 -e production -R /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru start`
 ←[32m2011-11-27T11:29:59+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m >> Thin web server (v1.2.6 codena
 me Crazy Delicious)
 ←[32m2011-11-27T11:29:59+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m >> Maximum connections set to 102
 4
 ←[32m2011-11-27T11:29:59+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m >> Listening on 0.0.0.0:16668, CT
 RL+C to stop
 ←[32m2011-11-27T11:30:00+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m State changed from starting to
 up
 ←[31m2011-11-27T11:30:01+00:00 heroku[router]:←[0m GET stormy-night-6239.heroku.
 com/ dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=230ms status=500 bytes=728
```

I don't see any errors there.

I also tried running heroku rake db:migrate 
And gotthis error :

```
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PGError: ERROR:  column "location_id" of relation "trips" already exists
: ALTER TABLE "trips" ADD COLUMN "location_id" integer
```

Currently I really don't understand what do, where to look and what to change.
Everything works fine on my local machine, tough!

Thanks for any help/ROR Newbie!

UPDATE:

after heroku rake db:reset

```
 Couldn't drop dahrzbhlza : #<ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PGError: ERROR:  mu
 st be owner of database dahrzbhlza
 : DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS "dahrzbhlza">
 dahrzbhlza already exists
 -- create_table("categories", {:force=>true})
 -> 0.0595s
 -- create_table("categories_trips", {:id=>false, :force=>true})
 -> 0.0031s
 -- create_table("details", {:force=>true})
 -> 0.0129s
 -- create_table("details_trips", {:id=>false, :force=>true})
 -> 0.0042s
 -- create_table("images", {:force=>true})
 -> 0.1982s
 -- create_table("locations", {:force=>true})
 -> 0.1065s
 -- create_table("trips", {:force=>true})
 -> 0.0422s
 -- create_table("users", {:force=>true})
 -> 0.1486s
 -- add_index("users", ["email"], {:name=>"index_users_on_email", :unique=>true})

 -> 0.0102s
 -- initialize_schema_migrations_table()
 -> 0.0017s
 -- assume_migrated_upto_version(20111116120713, ["/app/db/migrate"])
 -> 0.0091s
```

After heroku rake db:migrate:redo

```
 ==  AddTitleToImages: reverting ===============================================
 -- remove_column("images", :title)
 -> 0.0058s
 ==  AddTitleToImages: reverted (0.0059s) ======================================

 ==  AddTitleToImages: migrating ===============================================
 -- add_column(:images, :title, :string)
 -> 0.0032s
 ==  AddTitleToImages: migrated (0.0033s) ======================================
```

Another Question - why it is migrating only those two columns above - not all ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

another thing you'll want to do is move to the Cedar stack for Rails 3.1 sites - you're running on Bamboo from that stack trace - `heroku create --stack cedar` and then repush. You also won't need the rubyracer gem listed in your gemfile, it's very memory hungry and not required anymore on Cedar.

Answer (score 1):

Try rebuilding the database by pushing a working copy from your local machine. You can use [taps](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/taps) for that, like so

```
#On your local machine, that has a working database
$heroku db:push
```

Once they're the same, your migrations should start making more sense.

Comment: I've tried heroku db:push - still no changes, still the "We're sorry, but something went wrong. error"

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
group :production do
  # gems specifically for Heroku go here
  gem 'therubyracer-heroku', '0.8.1.pre3'
  gem "pg"
end
```

Comment: Ok I did it, but now I have another PGError: ERROR:. this time it is : ←[0m ActionView::Template::Error (PGEr
ror: ERROR:  relation "categories" does not exist - how can you fix them ?

Comment: run again heroku rake db:migrate and now it's only PGError: ERROR: column "location_id" of relation "trips" already exists : ALTER TABLE "trips" ADD COLUMN "location_id" integer

Comment: Now it seems your DB is broken in migration. If there is no important data in your DB, try to reset the DB with `heroku db:reset` and redo the migration.

Comment: Nope, still no luck - I've updated my question above, after heroku rake db:reset and heroku rake db:migrate:redo

Comment: hmmm, I had a similar problem for a few days and my answer above resolved this - sorry it hasn't brought you much luck. Another command to consider is 'heroku run rake db:migrate' as opposed to omitting the 'run' in your command. I will pop back again tomorrow when I am in the office and try to shed some light further if you are still stuck.